Python: Create table from string mixed with separators using FOR loops
I need to create a table with given width and height from 6 character string mixed with 2 separators without using import, def, if, else, while, iter, [ or ] etc., only with basic Python functions and FOR loops. Separator can't be at the beginning and at the end of the string.
For example, 3x5 table, string is Python, separators are + and -. The result is:
P+y-t+h-o
n+P-y+t-h
o+n-P+y-t
I have done it like this
# width = int(input("?"))
# height = int(input("?"))
# word = input("?")
# separators = input("?")
width = 13
height = 6
word = "matfyz"
separators = "()"
separator1, separator2 = separators
lenght = width * height
count = (lenght) // len(word) + 1
string = ""

for _ in range(count):
    for letter in word:
        string +=letter

for row in range(0, height):
    temp_separator=''
    for col in range(1, width+1):
        i=1
        print (temp_separator, end = '')
        for letter in string:
            need_this_letter = 1 - ((i != col+(width*row)) * 1)  #TODO: remove logic expression
            print (letter * need_this_letter, end='')
            i += 1
        temp_separator=separator1
        separator1, separator2 = separator2, separator1     
    print('')
    separator1, separator2 = separators

but there is a logic expression in this code (note: #TODO) that I still need to remove in order to comply with the set assignment only to use basic Python functions. Thank you all for any help !

You can get the result you seek via for loops, string slicing and the modulo operator.

Since the size of the word is always 6 letters and the separators are always 2 letters:
width = 5
height = 3
word = "Python"
sep1, sep2 = "+-"
l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6 = word
temp = ""

for _ in range(height):
    print(l1, end='')
    l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6 = l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l1
    for _ in range(width-1):
        print(sep1 + l1, end='')
        sep1,sep2 = sep2,sep1
        l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6 = l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l1
    print()

Output:
P+y-t+h-o
n+P-y+t-h
o+n-P+y-t

If your terminal supports the back space char:
for _ in range(height):
    for _ in range(width):
        print(l1 + sep1, end='')
        sep1,sep2 = sep2,sep1
        l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6 = l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l1
    sep1,sep2 = sep2,sep1
    print('\b ')


Given a WORD, WIDTH, and HEIGHT, we can iterate over the rows of HEIGHT and the columns of WIDTH then using some modulo math take appropriate slices of the letters of WORD and our SEPARATORS + and -
HEIGHT = 3
WIDTH = 5
WORD = "Python"
for row in range(HEIGHT):
    row_text = ""
    for column in range(WIDTH):
        index = (column - row) % len(WORD)
        separator = "+-"[column%2]
        row_text += WORD[index] + separator
    print(row_text[:-1])

That should give you:
P+y-t+h-o
n+P-y+t-h
o+n-P+y-t

At this point you could convert the above into list comprehensions and leverage str.join().

Solution based on string templates using the str.format method.
Set up the templates could be a bit dizzy but then you earn readability in the body of the program.
Notice that {{{}}} are used for escaping.
HEIGHT = 3
WIDTH = 5
WORD = "Python"


# template for right-pushing the characters of the word
n = len(WORD)
apply_right_push_template = (f"{{{n-1}}}" + ("{{{}}}"*(n-1)).format(*range(n-1))).format

# template for the alternated separators
apply_template = ("{}" + "{}".join("+-"*((WIDTH-1)//2) + "+"*(not WIDTH % 2)) + "{}").format


# apply iteratively the right-push of the characters and add separators
__WORD = WORD # temporary variable
print(apply_template(*__WORD))
for _ in range(HEIGHT-1):
    __WORD = apply_right_push_template(*__WORD)
    print(apply_template(*__WORD))

